# Basic Grails question: How does the following Grails code define personInstance?

Tags: grails, gsp

This is the GSP code generated by Grails for the view of the edit action for a `Person` domain object which is part of my model, and also happens to be the primary class for authentication by the ACEGI security plug-in.  I have snipped out a bunch of properties to keep it short.  The file resides in the standard location, `grails-app/views/person/edit.gsp`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.edit.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <span class="menuButton"><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}">Home</a></span>
            <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="list" action="list"><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></span>
            <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></span>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <h1><g:message code="default.edit.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <g:hasErrors bean="${personInstance}">
            <div class="errors">
                <g:renderErrors bean="${personInstance}" as="list" />
            </div>
            </g:hasErrors>
            <g:form method="post" >
                <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${personInstance?.id}" />
                <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${personInstance?.version}" />
                <div class="dialog">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr class="prop">
                                <td valign="top" class="name">
                                  <label for="username"><g:message code="person.username.label" default="Username" /></label>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: personInstance, field: 'username', 'errors')}">
                                    <g:textField name="username" value="${personInstance?.username}" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
...SNIP...
a bunch of props
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" /></span>
                    <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" /></span>
                </div>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is, how does the field `personInstance` get set up and populated?

I suspect this is a basic question which belies a fundamental lack of understanding on my part about how Grails works, but I need to know nonetheless.

This stems from the desire to create my own composite pages which access a `Person` object and its associated data, which is the heart of my app.  I was expecting to be able to create a new page alongside this one, let's call it `map.gsp`, and get at the `personInstance` in some magic way.  I can't figure out how to do that in spite of trying the obvious, and I think I have a gap right at the centre of my understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PersonInstance will be populated on the controller.
When you submit your form, the associated controller will receive a map containing the fields present on your form.

So, in your controller you'll find a command like

```
personInstance.properties = params
```

where params is a map containing the fields submited for the controller, which the keys are the names of the input elements you defined on your gsp file.

Comment: Thanks, that was the little hint I needed.  Some things have just fallen into place for me.  I have a second question about how to pass a parameter form the login page to my page using the default forward URI defined in security.groovy...  but I'll ask another question for that.